# why does true means false in bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement

Decisions with unexpected results

```
if [ false ]
then
  echo true
else
  echo false
fi

if [[ false ]]
then
  echo true
else
  echo false
fi

if [[ false -eq true ]]
then
  echo true
else
  echo false
fi
```

All decisions return true when logically they should return false!

Why?

Comment: See https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2158 and https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2309

Comment: Also, see my answer to [this Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1400335/how-does-bash-test-false).

Comment: What you want is `if false ...`. In your examples you proof only the existence of text.